# Receiving "Run-time error '2293': Microsoft Access can't send this e-mail message" after having no issues

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a button on an Access form that queues up an email and is linked to several fields on the form. Yesterday and this morning the button was working without issue. I have not changed the underlying code or any of the fields in the form, but suddenly the button is returning a `Run-time error '2293': Microsoft Access can't send this e-mail message` error message when I click it. An example of the code is as follows:

```
Private Sub cmd_Button_Click()

Dim toaddress As String
Dim ccaddress As String
Dim subject   As String
Dim message As String

toaddress = AddMailAddress(toaddress, Nz(Me.cmb_ProjectLead.Column(1), ""))
toaddress = AddMailAddress(toaddress, Nz(Me.cmb_ProjectLead2.Column(1), ""))
ccaddress = AddMailAddress(ccaddress, Nz(Me.cmb_OtherPOC.Column(1), ""))
ccaddress = AddMailAddress(ccaddress, Nz(Me.cmb_OtherPOC2.Column(1), ""))

subject = "text" & me.txb_ProjectName
message = "text" & me.txb_ProjectName & vbnewline & me.txb_ProjectLocation & vbnewline & me.txb_ProjectDescription

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , toaddress, ccaddress, , subject, message, True

End Sub
```

When I click "debug" on the error message, the line `DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , toaddress, ccaddress, , subject, message, True` is highlighted yellow with a yellow arrow pointed to it.

A few notes that may be helpful:
I'm working on a work issued computer and I have no Admin rights, so changing certain properties are not possible.
I have to use a VPN which has pretty strict security standards.
To reiterate, this worked up until today. In fact for the same record, it worked one moment, and then 30 seconds later did not work.

*Update: the command worked when I stripped everything except the sendobject line and replaced the values with text, i.e.

```
Private Sub cmd_Button_Click()
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , "toaddress", "ccaddress", , "subject", "message", True
End Sub
```

When I added just the `toaddress` and `ccaddress` back in, I got the 2293 error message.

*Additional info that may help: This form has several "Email To" buttons as well as some "Send Outlook Apppointment To" buttons. They all also worked fine up until this morning, but are now generating various error messages when clicked. They all use the same `toaddress, ccaddress, subject, message,` etc format as my example here.

The public function that is also linked to these commands is as follows:

```
Public Function AddMailAddress(address As String, newaddress As String)

    If (address = "") And (newaddress = "") Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If address = "" Then
        address = newaddress
    Else

        If Not newaddress = "" Then
            If VBA.Right(address, 1) = ";" Then
                address = address & newaddress
            Else
                address = address & ";" & newaddress
            End If
        End If
    End If


    AddMailAddress = address

End Function
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at beginning of procedure and step debug. Make sure variables get values.

Comment: Would you recommend putting the breakpoint on the first toaddress = , line, and then hitting Shift+F8 by making it step through the lines?

Comment: That's fine for breakpoint. Run function as normal - wherever it is called from - then progress one line at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime i get this error, it has nothing to do with the the database or the code, it is simply due to the fact that i have an outlook item open that is currently gettin edited that i have forgotten about.
Access cannot create a new Outlook item while there is currently an Outlook item open in edit mode.
Close down any Outlook items open in edit mode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The email buttons now work after closing out the database and re-opening it. Still no clue why it gave me run-time errors before. If it happens again, I'll be back to add more insight.